# Getting gcj to recognize java-8-openjdk libraries

Tags: ubuntu, native, java, gcj

I'm trying to use `gcj` to generate a stand alone executable. It works fine with java 1.5 that comes with gcj-4.8 when installed on Ubuntu 14.04. However if I want to use a later version of Java (such as 1.8) gcj doesn't understand the latest language libraries. I tried using `-I`, `--classpath`, and `--bootclasspath` to force it to use the 1.8 jdk (which is installed).

Any suggestions, or alternatives, to compile Java to a native executable?

Comment: `gcj` doesn't support any of the new language features either. The [homepage](https://gcc.gnu.org/java/) specifies that it *supports most of the 1.4 libraries plus some 1.5 additions*.

Comment: Amended formatting of answer as well as minor edits for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

The only alternative I can suggest is [Excelsior Jet](http://www.excelsiorjet.com/)

I did not personally used it, but studied native compilation long enough to know that for me, it's the most viable solution (in 2016).

Please note that it is not free for commercial use and not open source.

[Edit] As specified by Dmitry, Excelsior Jet is actually free for non commercial use. You'll find more info [here](http://www.excelsiorjet.com/free)